# Navbar carousel item background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navabar and carousel in the same section, what i want is when the carousel indicator becomes active it changes the background-color of the navbar and carousel item, any ideas on how to do that using jquery function?
Here is my jquery code for the indicators:

```
  $(document).ready(function(ev){
        $('#carousel-example-generic').on('slide.bs.carousel', function (evt) {
        $('#carousel-example-generic .controls li.active').removeClass('active');    
        $('#carousel-example-generic .controls li:eq('+$(evt.relatedTarget).index()+')').addClass('active');        
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.With jQuery, you can chain together `actions/methods`.
Chaining allows us to run multiple jQuery methods (on the same element) within a single statement.

```
    $('#carousel-example-generic .controls li:eq('+$(evt.relatedTarget).index()+')').css('background-color','green').addClass('active');   //sets background-color green
```

Comment: it worked, thanks. but i want it to change the navbar's and carousel item background not the indicator itself

Comment: set similarly for navar class.